# Как получить имя аккаунта google?

Tags: android

Создал метод
при клике на текст textView1 в лог с тегом Account выводится количество аккаунтов 0. Хотя у меня точно есть 1 аккаунт почему так?
И с ошибкой вылетает не может название аккаунта подставить в текст

разрешение тоже есть

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


public void onClick(View v){
  AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this); // current Context
  //AccountManager am = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE); // видел такой способ

  Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
  Log.i("Account", accounts.length + "");
  TextView tvInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  tvInfo.setText(accounts[0].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это:

```
 public String getUsername() {
AccountManager manager = 
AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
List<String> possibleEmails = new LinkedList<String>();

for (Account account : accounts) {
    // TODO: Check possibleEmail against an email regex or treat
    // account.name as an email address only for certain account.type
    // values.
    possibleEmails.add(account.name);
}

if (!possibleEmails.isEmpty() && possibleEmails.get(0) != null) {
    String email = possibleEmails.get(0);
    String[] parts = email.split("@");
    if (parts.length > 0 && parts[0] != null)
        return parts[0];
    else
        return null;
} else
    return null;
}
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: да разрешения добавил, не получается я даже не могу получить что у меня 1 аккаунт   

        Log.i("Account", accounts.length + ""); пишет 0

Answer (score 1):

У меня вот так работает

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />




    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    List<String> possibleEmails = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (Account account : accounts) {
        possibleEmails.add(account.name);
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
    //Log.e("", "Size: " + accounts.length);
    for (Account account : accounts) {

        String possibleEmail = account.name;
        String type = account.type;

        if (type.equals("com.google")) {
            strUserNameGmail= possibleEmail;
            break;
        }
    }
```